# Put a counter on the name of a variable

Tags: php, html, syntax, concatenation

What I wanna do is take the variable name `$ingreso` and increment it at the end to send a lot of variables with the same name but with a different number at the end,`$ingreso1`, `ingreso2` etc, but I don't know how to concatenate it correctly.
Please Help.

PHP Code:

```
 while ( $cont<= 15){           
      $sql = "INSERT INTO ingreso (vlr_ingreso, periodo_ingreso, proyecto_id_proyecto)
              VALUES ('$ingreso".$cont."','$cont','$proyecto_id');";
      $insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
```

But it keeps returning `$ingreso` without the number at the end.

What I think its happening is that the `$cont` is being added at the end of the `$ingreso` content, not to the variable itself

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks like you are concatenating it correctly, but not incrementing it.

Comment: Any time you find yourself doing this, you should really be using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the [complex string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) (`{}`).

```
while ( $cont<= 15){           
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ingreso (vlr_ingreso, periodo_ingreso, proyecto_id_proyecto)
          VALUES ('${'ingreso'.$cont}','$cont','$proyecto_id');";
    $insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

This way, the `${'ingreso'.$cont}` will be parsed within the string to `$ingreso1`, `$ingreso2`, etc.

(Also, as AbraCadaver commented, you'll also need to increment `$cont` for this to work.)

---

This would be easier if you could make changes earlier in your code so that these were array keys rather than separate variables. For example, if you had an array like:

```
$ingreso[1] = 'something';
$ingreso[2] = 'something else';
$ingreso[3] = 'etc.';
```

Then you could use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($ingreso as $periodo => $vlr) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ingreso (vlr_ingreso, periodo_ingreso, proyecto_id_proyecto)
            VALUES ('$vlr','$periodo','$proyecto_id');";
}
```